# Getting a PHP PDO connection, Handle it, use it

Tags: php, pdo

Hi can some one tell me if i have the right idea here for connecting to my database etc...
I have had some help with the config and handle. I would like to keep it all in class scope so i dont have a connection variable in my main file and just call the class functions i need.

This is what i have come up with..

config file

```
class siteDbc {

    protected function cfg() {

        return [

            'host' => 'localhost'

            ,'username' => ''

            ,'password' => ''

            ,'name' => ''

            ,'charset' => 'utf8mb4'

            ,'options' =>[

                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

                ,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

                ,PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false

            ]

        ];        

    }

}
```

Handle file

```
class siteDbh extends siteDbc {

    protected function connect() {

        try {

            // Get the variable values used to connect and login
            $dsn = "mysql:host={$this->cfg()['host']};dbname={$this->cfg()['name']};charset={$this->cfg()['charset']}";

            // Attempt to connect to the SQL database using PDO(Prepared Database Object)
            // Send the Database name, user and pass to the PDO class to try and connect
            // Attribute "options" included
            return new PDO($dsn, $this->cfg()['username'], $this->cfg()['password'], $this->cfg()['options']);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            die($e->getMessage());

        }

    }

}
```

Then i include them in my main file

```
require_once INCLUDES_BASEDIR.'_site_pdo/_sitePDO-dbc.cfg.php';
require_once INCLUDES_BASEDIR.'_site_pdo/_sitePDO-dbh.class.php';
```

then a class of public functions for http settings to be used in the main file

```
class siteHTTP extends siteDbh {

    // Select HTTP request

    public function request() {

        $sql = "SELECT http_request FROM settings WHERE 1";

        if (!$stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql)) {

            return false;

        } else {

            return $stmt->fetch()['http_request'];

        }

    }

    //#

    // Select Domain

    public function domain() {

        $sql = "SELECT site_domain FROM settings WHERE 1";

        if (!$stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql)) {

            return false;

        } else {

            return $stmt->fetch()['site_domain'];

        }

    }

    //#

    // Select Directory

    public function directory() {

        $sql = "SELECT site_url_dir FROM settings WHERE 1";

        if (!$stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql)) {

            return false;

        } else {

            return $stmt->fetch()['site_url_dir'];

        }

    }

    //#

}
```

and then in my main file i do somthing like this

```
require_once INCLUDES_BASEDIR.'_site_pdo/_sitePDO-http.class.php';

$siteHTTP = new siteHTTP;

// Get URL Data - Force HTTPS or HTTP

// SITE HTTP Array

define('SITE_HTTP', array(

    'request' => $siteHTTP->request(),

    'domain' => $siteHTTP->domain(),

    'directory' => $siteHTTP->directory()

));

// Site URL - A combination of HTTP Request and Site Domain and Directory of site gives you a full URL string
define('SITE_URL', SITE_HTTP['request'].SITE_HTTP['domain'].SITE_HTTP['directory']);
//#

// Force HTTP HOST to be the actual HOST (yourdomain.com)
// HTTP HOST is a security. NOTE I only use this 
// Server Global ONCE here to make sure domain.com is 
// domain.com and not hackyourshit.com.
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != SITE_HTTP['domain']) {
    header('Location: '.SITE_HTTP['request'].SITE_HTTP['domain'].trim(htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8')));
    exit;
} else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) == false) {
    die('Access Denied!');
}
//#

// Force HTTPS - SSL TLS ON
if (SITE_HTTP['request'] === 'https://') {
    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "off") {
        //header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: '.SITE_URL);
        exit;
    }
    // Force HTTP - SSL TLS OFF
} else if (SITE_HTTP['request'] === 'http://') {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
        //header('HTTPS/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: '.SITE_URL);
        exit;
    }
}
//#
```

And another example of using a function inside the main file and this checks for a genuine session. There is more to it then this of course.

```
require_once INCLUDES_BASEDIR.'_site_pdo/_sitePDO-checkUserSessionID.class.php';

    $verifyUserSessionID = new checkUserSessionID;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Check the users Session ID matches the Session ID in the database

    if (!$verifyUserSessionID->sidCheck($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['sessionid'])) {

        // This will only be called if a users active session ID

        // changes in the database due to logging into another device or an intruder

        // Session does not exist

        logout($sessionUpdateID, 'MIN');

        header('Location: '.SITE_URL.'?sysmsg=sidinvalid'.$sysMsgCon.$randSysMsgID);

        exit;

    }
```

Will it be better using an if statement for my handle and just return false so i can handle the error from my main file myself, if the connection is false??

completely self taught here, advice/help is appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Why not use an already existing PDO wrapper?

Comment: dont extend the db class only to use it `class siteHTTP extends siteDbh` instead use dependency injection or extend a DI container which also pulls in the db class, else your find your only be able to extend the db class because most of your code uses a db

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ive heard [grumpy pdo](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) is a nice wrapper, I revamped it a while back plopped it [here](https://github.com/phppackage/pdo-wrapper) ;p

Comment: Not inventing. It's pretty basic realy! I just need to know if its Valid code and if not where do i need to improve or fix?  Thanks

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Where did you hear it was a nice wrapper? :) That's pretty cool, glad you are getting some use out of it. I use GrumpyPDO in _all_ of my projects

Comment: Could some one show me a structural example with what i have here please?

Comment: I can see why people would use a wrapper but i love learning about what every part of my code does...

Comment: @Jimbo GrumpyPDO, which Lawrence linked above, is a very simple (yet also extremely powerful) class. If you just look at the code, you could probably figure out exactly what it does and how it does it.

Comment: to be honest, there is so little point in having such a wrapper and you managed to make so many mistakes that your wrapper is hardly salvageable. See my article on the [common mistakes](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)